# why multiple ssl connection to web server

Tags: https, webserver, wireshark

I wrote a webserver and using firefox to test. I am using https,
I observed browser opens multiple connections(figured this out by wireshark stream index) , on each connection it does SSL key exchange.
Is this the correct way for browser to work ?, I assume browser  is trying to achieve parallelism to download multiple file , But then the issue is multiple SSL negotiation happen so many time.

Another thing, look like wireshark stream index parameter indirectly point to those many connect the client make , is this observation correct ?